# How can I get JSON response without delay

Tags: android, json

Is there anyway to get json response instant this is my 1st time studying json sorry for my grammar and to my code.

I tried to put a delay when execute I want to find another way without using handler.postdelay I want to get the data without delay.

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
           un = args[0];
           up = args[1];
            try {
                StringBuilder JSON_DATA = new StringBuilder();
                URL url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data_string = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(un,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(up,"UTF-8");
                        bufferedWriter.write(data_string);
                        bufferedWriter.flush();
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                InputStream  in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                while ((JSON_STRING = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    JSON_DATA.append(JSON_STRING).append("\n");
                }
                String x = JSON_DATA.toString().trim();
                if(x.equals("1"))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                return JSON_DATA.toString().trim();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;            
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            json_string = result;
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().hide(); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    B1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnloginok);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pname);
    //new BackgroundTask().execute();
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

## this is what I try to get the response

```
public void login(View v)
{
    String uname = un.getText().toString();
    String upass = pass.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(uname,upass);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
            if(json_string==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Try Again..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,intro.class);
                intent.putExtra("json_data", json_string);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    }, 4000);       
}
```

}

Sometimes I get null in response.

Comment: There needs to be a delay because You're using network connection to obtain the data, Also your question is misleading because its problem with waiting for async task, nothing particular with json parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about `AsyncTask` at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Using `Handler` for waiting for a network call response is not the right way. Right now you are waiting for 4 seconds, if response comes back in 5 you would get null in json string.

When you are using `AsyncTask` for a network call, then `onPostExecute` is the callback when data is received back.

You should change activity in `onPostExecute`. Change the `login` method like below

```
public void login(View v)
{
    String uname = un.getText().toString();
    String upass = pass.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
    backgroundTask.execute(uname,upass);
}
```

Create a new method like this

```
private void onLoginResponse(String json){
    if(json==null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Try Again..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,intro.class);
        intent.putExtra("json_data", json);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now call this method in `onPostExecute` like this

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    json_string = result;
    onLoginResponse(json_string);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much it really helps me a lot I really mean it

Comment: If this solved the issue then you should accept this as answer. I'd appreciate that.